# fields_for helper: Need to render one text area in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes, nested-loops, form-helpers

I'm having trouble with fields_for helper in rails. I have a Question model that has_many answers.
When I display the form for a user to fill in answers I only want one text area to render for a particular question. With my current loop construct, it renders 3 text areas per question. (They are 3 questions in my example).

Ok the code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns panel">
    <%= form_for(@evaluation_form) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'application/errors', f: f %>

        <%= f.fields_for :questions do |question_form| %>
          <p><%= question_form.object[:title]  %></p>

          <%= question_form.fields_for :evaluation_form_answers do |answer_form| %> 

            <%= answer_form.text_area :answer, value: question_form.object.evaluation_form_answers.where(["student_id = ? and evaluation_form_question_id = ?", "#{current_student.id}", "#{question_form.object[:id]}"]).first.answer %>
            <%= answer_form.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id%>  

          <%end%>

        <%end%>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Submit Evaluation Form" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

My controller code:

```
 def answer        
       @evaluation_form.questions.each do |question|        
         question.evaluation_form_answers.build
       end    
  end
```

Relationships between models involved:

```
Question: has_many :evaluation_form_answers  
          accepts_nested_attributes_for :evaluation_form_answers, allow_destroy: true  

EvaluationFormAnswer : belongs_to :evaluation_form_question
```

Screenshot of problem:[image]

Comment: Can you post your controller and model code? Also, the relationship between `Question` and `EvaluationFormAnswer` should be `has_one`/`belongs_to` — is it?

Comment: @zeantsoi hi ive updated my question. Question has_many answers and answer belongs_to question

Comment: Can you post your full controller code, or at least the action that renders the view depicted?

Comment: @zeantsoi i posted my controller code related to the view.

Comment: Okay, I've proposed a fix below.

Comment: Its of no help. @zeantsoi

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Controller

```
def answer        
     @evaluation_form.questions.each do |question|        
         @answer_form = question.evaluation_form_answers.build
     end
end
```

View

```
<%= question_form.fields_for :evaluation_form_answers, @answer_form do |answer_form| %>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this railscasts episode [Rails Casts Nested Model Form episode 196](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast)